# 1 to 1 database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a database and normally users are the central object.
In database I have a tables `roles` and `users in roles` so I can give users different permissions on site.
But now I have one doubt.
I saw before one database with structure like this (User is in 1:1 relation to other tables):

```
User{UserId, Username, Email etc.}
Admin{UserId, some specific columns}
Child{UserId, some specific columns}
Admin{Parent, some specific columns}
```

and other tables are connected to user not through User table but through `Admin, Child and admin.`
Because now I design my database I have Users and user can be `Admin, CompanyManager and Professor`.
I wonder should I design table like I show above or just relied on roles?
What is advantage of the first approach?
And also in my business model User doesn't have to be CompanyManager or Professor so this is actually 1 to 0 or 1 design.
What is a good way to design database with scenario like this?

Comment: That's not a 1:1 relationship, it's a 1:0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of having specific tables for certain types of users is to store information that is only relevant to that class of user.

In your example,

- perhaps all users would have a manager - so the manager ID would go in the users column.
- managers would have permissions to view certain information, so this would be handled via a role.
- only professors would have a Subject, or the "HasTenure" property. So this information would go in a professors table. Using this approach, you avoid the need to have a "Subject" column in the users table, when it is only applicable to a certain subset of users. As such you avoid a functional dependency in the users table, and a violation of 3rd Normal Form.

Comment: Ok this concept is really important for me to understand as I see that this is not bad practice. A question: I have a Users table with general user columns. And I need a few others that ARE users but need some extra columns. From your answer I understand that the best way to go is to create tables that are 1 to 1 with user table. But when I register new user in a system do I need to add him to all those 1:1 tables or I can somehow make this optional? For example after register to save data only to Users and later on user request to add it to Professor for example?

Comment: @1110 You only create entries in the Professors table for users who are professors - the relationship between users and professors is normally denoted as 1:0.  If you added all users to the professors table whether professors or not, then there would be no benefit at all to this design :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach:

[image]

In this way, you can easily group Roles into categories and assign them to users.